# Generate a WITH clause/UNIONs from a SELECT

Tags: sql, oracle, common-table-expression, oracle18c

I want to generate a WITH clause/UNIONs — for the purpose of easily sharing ***small*** samples of data  (10-20 rows).

I want to do that without creating tables or inserting rows.

---

Example:

Take a table or query like this:

[image]

...and generate this:

```
with cte as(
select 10 as asset_id, 1 as vertex_num, 118.56 as x, 3.8 as y from dual
union all
select 10 as asset_id, 2 as vertex_num, 118.62 as x, 1.03 as y from dual
union all
select 10 as asset_id, 3 as vertex_num, 121.93 as x, 1.03 as y from dual)

 --There are lots more rows. But it's too much work to write them all out.
   
select * from cte
```

Using SQL, how can I automatically generate a WITH clause/UNIONs from the resultset?

- I believe there is OOTB export functionality in Toad that can do that. But I don't think there are any tools in SQL Developer that can do it, which is what I'm using.
- When attempting this with SQL, I think the main challenge is to loop through *n* columns. I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: It's entirely possible to generate strings with SQL, but the engine imposes limitations on the size of an executable SQL statement (400k?) that woud probably limit the number of data rows you can render.

Comment: @Ok. Cool. I only need it to work for 10-20 rows. Just a small sample. I'll update the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be easier to use `xmltable` or (`json_table` for Oracle 12+) for such purposes.

Example with `xmltable`:

1. Just aggregate all the required data into `xmltype`:
   you can use `xmltype(cursor(select...from...))`:

```sql
select xmltype(cursor(select * from test)) xml from dual;
```

or `dbms_xmlgen.getxmltype(query_string)`:

```sql
select dbms_xmlgen.getxmltype('select * from test') xml from dual;
```

2. then you can use the returned XML with

```
xmltable('/ROWSET/ROW' passing xmltype(your_xml) columns ...)
```

Example:

```
select *
from xmltable(
        '/ROWSET/ROW'
        passing xmltype(q'[<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ROWSET>
 <ROW>
  <ASSET_ID>10</ASSET_ID>
  <VERTEX_NUM>1</VERTEX_NUM>
  <X>118.56</X>
  <Y>3.8</Y>
 </ROW>
 <ROW>
  <ASSET_ID>10</ASSET_ID>
  <VERTEX_NUM>2</VERTEX_NUM>
  <X>118.62</X>
  <Y>1.03</Y>
 </ROW>
</ROWSET>
        ]')
    columns 
        asset_id,vertex_num,x,y
) test
```

Full example on [DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=036b718f2b18df898c3e3de722c97378): https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=036b718f2b18df898c3e3de722c97378

Comment: I was going to be picky and point out that makes everything in the CTE strings; but that's easy enough to fix by adding the data types in the `columns` clause, and setting NLS to ISO formats (though that might not quite work for dates with non-midnight times). Nice approach.

Comment: thanks @AlexPoole I just really use this approach sometimes with my clients for performance tasks when I have no direct access to databases: I just create a short script that aggregates all required info (selects from ASH, AWR, v$sql, v$sql_shared_cursor, etc) into XMLs and then I can analyze them using SQL or just Excel...

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`dbms_sql`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/DBMS_SQL.html#GUID-C96D5BAA-29A9-4AB5-A69E-E31228ECC9E9) to execute a query against your real table, interrogate the [data types](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-7B72E154-677A-4342-A1EA-C74C1EA928E6), and use that information to generate the CTE and its inner queries.

As a first stab:

```
create or replace procedure print_cte (p_statement varchar2) as
  -- dbms_sql variables
  l_c pls_integer;
  l_col_cnt pls_integer;
  l_rows pls_integer;
  l_desc_t dbms_sql.desc_tab;

  l_first_row boolean := true;
  l_varchar2 varchar2(4000);
  l_number number;
  l_date date;
  -- etc.
begin
  -- ideally add some checks for p_statement being a sinple query

  l_c := dbms_sql.open_cursor;
  dbms_sql.parse(c => l_c, statement => p_statement, language_flag => dbms_sql.native);
  l_rows := dbms_sql.execute(c => l_c);

  dbms_sql.describe_columns(c => l_c, col_cnt => l_col_cnt, desc_t => l_desc_t);

  -- define columns, and output CTE columns at the same time
  dbms_output.put('with cte (');

  for i in 1..l_col_cnt loop
    case l_desc_t(i).col_type
      when 1 then
        dbms_sql.define_column(c => l_c, position=> i, column => l_varchar2, column_size => 4000);
      when 2 then
        dbms_sql.define_column(c => l_c, position=> i, column => l_number);
      when 12 then
        dbms_sql.define_column(c => l_c, position=> i, column => l_date);
      -- etc. plus else to skip or throw error for anything not handled
    end case;

    if i > 1 then
      dbms_output.put(', ');
    end if;
    dbms_output.put('"' || l_desc_t(i).col_name || '"');
  end loop;

  dbms_output.put(') as (');

  while dbms_sql.fetch_rows(c => l_c) > 0 loop
    if (l_first_row) then
      l_first_row := false;
    else
      dbms_output.put('  union all');
    end if;
    dbms_output.new_line;
 
    for i in 1..l_col_cnt loop
      if i = 1 then
        dbms_output.put('  select ');
      else
        dbms_output.put(', ');
      end if;
 
      case l_desc_t(i).col_type
        when 1 then
          dbms_sql.column_value(c => l_c, position => i, value => l_varchar2);
          dbms_output.put(q'[']' || l_varchar2 || q'[']');
        when 2 then
          dbms_sql.column_value(c => l_c, position => i, value => l_number);
          dbms_output.put(l_number);
        when 12 then
          dbms_sql.column_value(c => l_c, position => i, value => l_date);
          dbms_output.put(q'[to_date(']'
            || to_char(l_date, 'SYYYY-MM-DD-HH24:MI:SS')
            || q'[', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')]');
        -- etc. plus else to skip or throw error for anything not handled
     end case;
    end loop;

    dbms_output.put(' from dual');
    dbms_output.new_line;
  end loop;

  dbms_output.put_line(')');
  dbms_output.put_line('select * from cte;');
  
  dbms_sql.close_cursor(c => l_c);
end print_cte;
/
```

and then you can do:

```
begin
  print_cte('select * from your_table');
end;
/
```

which produces:

```
with cte ("ASSET_ID", "VERTEX_NUM", "X", "Y") as (
  select 10, 1, 118.56, 3.8 from dual
  union all
  select 10, 2, 118.62, 1.03 from dual
  union all
  select 10, 3, 121.93, 1.03 from dual
)
select * from cte;
```

Your client has to be configured to handle dbms_output, of course.

As noted in the inline comments you should check the passed-in statement isn't going to do something nasty; and you need to add handling for other data types. This is just a starting point.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=8c275d1add36a3fe5b13134fa9384f06)

Answer (score 1):

I know my answer is not pure SQL or PLSQL.

But I suggest you to use Javascript to generate CTE query because data is small.

Javascript is very easy and maintainable than SQL or PLSQL in your case.

You can use this small script in here whenever you want. (No additional editor needed)
https://jsfiddle.net/pLvgr8oh/

Or you can run script with Chrome browser if you worried about security.
https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/javascript/snippets/

```js
function convertToSelect(tsv, firstRowIsColumn, columnsComma, typesComma) {
  function getCol(column, value, type) {
    // In case type is 'date', after colon is date format
    const [ typeNew, dateFormat ] = type.split(':')

    switch (typeNew) {
      case 'string': return `'${value}' as ${column}`
      case 'number': return `${value} as ${column}`
      case 'date': return `to_date('${value}', '${dateFormat}') as ${column}`
    }
  }

  const columns = columnsComma ? columnsComma.split(',') : []
  const types = typesComma ? typesComma.split(',') : []

  // Split row by '\r\n' or '\n'
  const list = tsv.split(/\r*\n/)
  const colCount = list[0].split(/\t/).length

  let columnsNew = []
  let typesNew = types

  // If first row is column name
  if (firstRowIsColumn) {
    columnsNew = list[0].split(/\t/);
    list.shift(0)
  }

  // If column name is specified then override column names in first row
  if (columns.length > 0) {
    columnsNew = columns
  }

  // If type is not specified set all type to 'string'
  if (typesNew.length === 0) {
    typesNew = [...Array(colCount)].map(t => 'string')
  }

  const rows = list.map(item => {
    // [ '2 as F_INT', '2.223 as F_LONG'... ]
    const cols = item
    .split(/\t/)
    .map((value, index) => {
      return getCol(columnsNew[index], value, typesNew[index])
    })
    .join(', ')

    // select 2 as F_INT, 2.223 as F_LONG... from dual
    return `    select ${cols} from dual`
  })

  const selectUnion = rows.join(`
union all
`)
  return `with cte as
(
${selectUnion}
)
select * from cte;
`
}

const tsv = `F_INT  F_LONG  F_VARCHAR   F_DATE
1   1.123   a   2022-12-01
2   2.223   b   2022-12-02
3   3.323   c   2022-12-03`
const firstRowIsColumn = true
const columnsComma = 'v_num,v_lng,v_str,v_date'
//const columnsComma = ''
const typesComma = 'number,number,string,date:YYYY-MM-DD'
//const typesComma = ''
const ret = convertToSelect(tsv, firstRowIsColumn, columnsComma, typesComma)
console.log(ret)
```

which generates (if the snippet doesn't mangle the tab characters):

```
with cte as
(
    select 1 as v_num, 1.123 as v_lng, 'a' as v_str, to_date('2022-12-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') as v_date from dual
union all
    select 2 as v_num, 2.223 as v_lng, 'b' as v_str, to_date('2022-12-02', 'YYYY-MM-DD') as v_date from dual
union all
    select 3 as v_num, 3.323 as v_lng, 'c' as v_str, to_date('2022-12-03', 'YYYY-MM-DD') as v_date from dual
)
select * from cte;
```

Comment: Interesting approach, but your generated CTE isn't valid. You are missing commas between the column expressions, aliases for the columns, quotes around strings, and even with quotes `'2022-12-01'` is a string rather than a date.

Comment: @AlexPoole Oh, That is because stackoverflow changed my tab(\t) character to space in tsv variable. I will modify tonight because I'm busy. You can see right result in jsfiddle.net link.

Comment: I see... it also works if you run the snippet from the answer in edit mode, oddly, so there seems to be a bug in snippets somewhere. I've pasted in the real output to make it clearer that it does work.

Comment: @AlexPoole I was planning to modify Javascript code to add function when two or more space is separation. But I found it's more reasonable to keep code and leaving comment about bug after seeing your edition. If someone need to apply both tab and 2 or more space for separation, just replace `/\t/` with `/\t| {2,}/`.